Could not call function from another class; Error: FrameLft.on_clickMB() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

frameLH = 120


def main_window():  # ========================== Main Window ==============================
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("950x650")
    window.minsize(750, 625)
    window.configure(bg='#65A8E1')

    FrameTop(window)
    FrameBot(window)
    FrameLft(window)
    FrameRgt(window)
    window.mainloop()


class FrameTop:  # ============================ Top Frame =================================
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.frame_top = tk.Frame(root, height=100, bg="#70AD47", relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=5)
        self.frame_top.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.TOP)

        self.btnM = (tk.Button(self.frame_top, bg="#4472C4", fg="White", bd=2, font=("Calibre", 12, 'bold'), activebackground='#ED7D31', text="Menu", command=FrameLft.on_clickMB))
        
`# could not call function from other class FrameLft ====`
        self.btnM.place(x=10, y=45)


class FrameBot:  # ============================ Bottom Frame =================================
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        frame_bot = Frame(root, height=45, bg="#4472C4", relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=5)  # blue
        frame_bot.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)


class FrameLft:  # ============================ Left Frame =================================
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.frame_lft = tk.Frame(root, width=120, bg="#ED7D31", relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=5) 
        self.frame_lft.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)

    def on_clickMB(self):  # ========================= Minimize/Maximize Menu ====================
        global frameLH

        if frameLH == 120:
            self.frame_lft.config(width=70)
            frameLH = 70
        elif frameLH == 70:
            self.frame_lft.config(width=120)
            frameLH = 120


class FrameRgt:  # ============================ Right Frame =================================
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        frame_rgt = tk.Frame(self.root, width=130, bg="#FFC000", relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=5) 
        frame_rgt.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_window()



I have defined a function "on_clickMB(self)" in class "FrameLft".
I want to call this function by tk.Button placed in class "FrameTop".
On clicking the tk.Button, the error shows: TypeError: FrameLft.on_clickMB() is missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.
The frames should be in sequence: FrameTop, FrameBot, FrameLft, and FrameRgt.

This error occurs because with the button you call a new class and not the old class that you have initialised before. You should save the classes in variables and then call the functions via the variables.
This code should work:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

frameLH = 120


def main_window():  # ========================== Main Window ==============================
    global frame_top, frame_bottom, frame_left, frame_right
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("950x650")
    window.minsize(750, 625)
    window.configure(bg='#65A8E1')

    frame_left = FrameLft(window)
    frame_right = FrameRgt(window)
    frame_top = FrameTop(window)
    frame_bottom = FrameBot(window)
    window.mainloop()


class FrameTop:  # ============================ Top Frame =================================
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.frame_top = tk.Frame(root, height=100, bg="#70AD47", relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=5)
        self.frame_top.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.TOP)

        self.btnM = (tk.Button(self.frame_top, bg="#4472C4", fg="White", bd=2, font=("Calibre", 12, 'bold'), activebackground='#ED7D31', text="Menu", command=frame_left.on_clickMB()))
        
# could not call function from other class FrameLft ====
        self.btnM.place(x=10, y=45)


class FrameBot:  # ============================ Bottom Frame =================================
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        frame_bot = Frame(root, height=45, bg="#4472C4", relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=5)  # blue
        frame_bot.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)


class FrameLft:  # ============================ Left Frame =================================
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.frame_lft = tk.Frame(root, width=120, bg="#ED7D31", relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=5) 
        self.frame_lft.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)

    def on_clickMB(self):  # ========================= Minimize/Maximize Menu ====================
        global frameLH

        if frameLH == 120:
            self.frame_lft.config(width=70)
            frameLH = 70
        elif frameLH == 70:
            self.frame_lft.config(width=120)
            frameLH = 120


class FrameRgt:  # ============================ Right Frame =================================
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        frame_rgt = tk.Frame(self.root, width=130, bg="#FFC000", relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=5) 
        frame_rgt.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_window()


Note that command=frame_left.on_clickMB() will execute frame_left.on_clickMB() immediately, not when the button is clicked.  It should be command=frame_left.on_clickMB instead.  Also you create frame_left first that breaks the desired layout required by OP.
